# does it takes someone out opf the fold of islam

Tags: shirk, kufr

i'm a student and learning coding, i get coding questions to solve them,
in that there some thing that if we add happy + christmas ,then what we get the solution

solution is : happy christmas

is this kufr to write or selecting these kufr options